# Having trouble with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Need to generate courses list and count

1. all
2. unanswered
3. answered but unchecked

Questions.

Here's my query

```
SELECT c.id, 
    c.name, 
    COUNT(allq.id) 'All', 
    COUNT(unanswered.id) 'Unanswered',
    COUNT(unchecked.id) 'Unchecked'
FROM courses c
LEFT JOIN `courses-lessons` cl 
    ON c.id = cl.cid
LEFT JOIN lesson_questions allq 
    ON cl.id = allq.lid
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT q.id, a.qid, q.lid
    FROM lesson_questions q
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT id, qid
        FROM answers
        WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT aid FROM answer_chk_results)
    ) a 
        ON q.id = a.qid 
) unchecked 
    ON cl.id = unchecked.lid
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM lesson_questions
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT qid FROM answers)
) unanswered 
    ON cl.id = unchecked.lid
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

and here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d23b4/5)

Database structure

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9ExyO6ktYcOenZ1WlBwdlY2R3c

I added 3 questions as sample data, but query calculates all questions and returns 9. It's impossible. Something goes wrong. Can't figure out, what am I missing.

## Update

I will explain some of tables:

1. `answer_chk_results` - checked answers table. So if some answer doesn't exist on this table, it means it's unchecked
2. `lesson_questions` - lesson <-> question associations (by id) table
3. `courses-lessons` - courses <-> lessons associations (by id) table

Only first problem seems not so difficult: To get all questions' count of course, my plan looks like below:

1. At first, we need to get all courses names list. Query will look like so:

   SELECT c.id, c.name FROM courses c
2. Then get all lessons from `courses-lessons` association table by every selected course from `1.` (Have no idea how to continue previous query)
3. Then, count **all questions** by selected lesson id (`lid` column) from `2.`

Comment: @epic_synatax: Can you explain how's table relating to each other. it will help in understanding your query.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk updated questions. check out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using conditional count statements, so you don't need all the sub queries:

```
SELECT  c.ID,
        c.Name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT q.ID) AS Questions,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.ID IS NULL THEN q.ID END) AS UnAnswered,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN cr.ID IS NULL AND a.ID IS NOT NULL THEN q.ID END) AS UnChecked
FROM    Courses c
        LEFT JOIN `Courses-Lessons` cl
            ON cl.CID = c.ID
        LEFT JOIN Lesson_Questions q
            ON cl.ID = q.LID
        LEFT JOIN Answers a
            ON a.QID = q.ID
        LEFT JOIN Answer_chk_results cr
            ON a.ID = cr.AID
GROUP BY c.ID --, c.Name
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d23b4/18)**

---

**EDIT**

```
SELECT  c.ID,
        c.Name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT q.ID) AS Questions,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.ID IS NULL THEN q.ID END) AS UnAnswered,
        COUNT(a.ID) AS Answers,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN cr.ID IS NULL THEN a.ID END) AS UnChecked
FROM    Courses c
        LEFT JOIN `Courses-Lessons` cl
            ON cl.CID = c.ID
        LEFT JOIN Lesson_Questions q
            ON cl.LID = q.LID
        LEFT JOIN Answers a
            ON a.QID = q.QID
        LEFT JOIN Answer_chk_results cr
            ON a.ID = cr.AID
GROUP BY c.ID, c.Name
```

Comment: Tested it first on SQL fiddle with sample data. (Real data is huge, so I can't place it on sqlfiddle) It returned some values. Thought works well. But while I test it with real data, see that returns wrong values. Forex, when I manually count, result for all questions count must be 25, but it returns 27. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. MySQL server running on my local machine, so I can give you teamviewer (http://teamviewer.com) id and password if you want to connect to my desktop remotely and test query with real data.

Comment: There is no reason from the SQL that you should be getting duplicates, I would expect the discrepency to be down to duplicates in the data. I think this will be avoided by adding `DISTINCT` to the `COUNT`s, if this still shows 27 then you have 27 question IDs and your manual count must be wrong.

Comment: Are you there? What can be wrong with `unchecked`? it shows exactly same result as `questions`

Comment: I have made an edit, it was counting questions, not answers, so even if the question had not been answered, it was counted as unchecked. You may also need to add further criteria to see if the `checked` column in `Answer_chk_results` is 1 or 0.

Comment: Again wrong count for `unchecked` . BTW,`Answer_chk_results` already has `checked` column. (But I think it's pointless, because table contains only checked answer id's)

Comment: In the SQLFiddle you gave there were no records in `Answer_chk_results` so this was correct to show as 3? I have added an entry in a [new Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0708b/1) and the unchecked column decreases to 2. Can you explain in more detail why the counts are wrong? thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16030/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-garethd)

Comment: Please join chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16030/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-garethd

Answer (score 3):

Maybe - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d23b4/42

```
SELECT  c.ID,
        c.Name,
        COUNT(q.ID) AS 'Questions',
        SUM(CASE WHEN a.ID IS NOT NULL Then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Unanswered',
        SUM(CASE WHEN cr.ID IS NOT NULL Then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Unchecked'
FROM    Courses c
        LEFT JOIN `Courses-Lessons` cl
            ON cl.CID = c.ID
        LEFT JOIN Lesson_Questions q
            ON cl.ID = q.LID
        LEFT JOIN Answers a         
            ON a.QID = q.ID             
        LEFT JOIN Answer_chk_results cr
            ON a.ID = cr.AID
GROUP BY c.ID
```

Comment: And what is difference between first and your answers?

Comment: I didn't see the first answer when I edited it, but there are 2 differences. He counts and I add 1 to a counter ( `COUNT(CASE WHEN a.ID IS NULL THEN q.ID END) AS UnAnswered` vs. `SUM(CASE WHEN a.ID IS NOT NULL Then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Unanswered',` ). And down below you don't need `GROUP BY c.ID, c.Name`, `GROUP BY c.ID` is better. Best answer, I think, is Gareth's answer with my GROUP BY

Comment: He also wrote `GROUP BY c.ID, c.Name`. why your then?

Comment: 2 reasons : 1. `GROUP BY c.ID` is faster than `GROUP BY c.ID, c.Name` 2. c.ID is unique so is absolutely no logic in making `GROUP BY c.ID, c.Name`

Comment: `GROUP BY c.ID`'s time is 0.001 while `GROUP BY c.ID, c.Name`'s time is 0.006. Yeah you'r right, I don't want to waste 0.005 second of golden time of visitors and mine. So Upvote his answer too, please

Comment: Tested it first on SQL fiddle with sample data. (Real data is huge, so I can't place it on sqlfiddle) It returned some values. Thought works well. But while I test it with real data, see that returns wrong values. Forex, when I manually count, result for all questions count must be 25, but it returns 27. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. MySQL server running on my local machine, so I can give you teamviewer (http://teamviewer.com) id and password if you want to connect to my desktop remotely and test query with real